# Why does my compiler gives me a Segmentation Fault when I execute this code?

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

struct Node* takeInput(){
    struct Node* head;
    cout<<"Enter element:";
    int data;
    cin>>data;
    while(data!=-1){
        struct Node* newNode=new (struct Node);
        newNode->data=data;
        newNode->next=NULL;

        if(head==NULL){
            head=newNode;
        }
        else{
            struct Node* temp=new (struct Node);
            while(temp->next!=NULL){
                temp=temp->next;
            }
            temp->next=newNode;
        }
        cout<<"Enter next element: ";
        cin>>data;
    }
    return head;
}

void print(struct Node* head){


    while(head->next!=NULL){
        cout<<head->data<<"->";
        head=head->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    struct Node* head = new (struct Node);
    head = takeInput();
    print(head);
}
```

The segmentation fault occurs when the print() function executes.
Without the execution of the print function the code runs perfectly. The code takes the input from the user but crashes when I try to print the Linked List.
I am using a gcc compiler with Code Blocks IDE on a Linux OS.

Comment: Compiler doesn't give you segmentation fault. It's your program who is "giving" it.

Comment: What will happen if you pass `nullptr` to your `print` function?

Comment: `while(temp->next!=NULL){` is checking `next` of a new node, who's members are uninitialized. You likely meant to line just before to be `temp = head;` rather than allocating a new node.

Comment: In modern C++ it's not necessary to specify `struct Node`, you can just use `Node`. This eliminates a lot of needless verbosity.

Comment: `temp = new...` why?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Correct. But a solution to this will be more welcomed. Thanks

Comment: @manni66 probably because OP wants node to outlive the function. `uniuque_ptr` is possibly a better choice here, but for a linked list automated destruction can get ugly. `head = new`, on the other hand, is a bit puzzling. Looks like a  leak.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That segment of the code runs perfectly

Comment: One problem is that `struct Node* head` does not initialize `head` to `NULL`. You need to explicitly initialize pointers if you want them to have a determinate value after initialization. `struct Node* head = NULL` gets you somewhere

Comment: Best advice for understanding a linked list I've ever heard is to draw the sucker out on a piece of paper. Follow all of your instructions like a computer would and try to make a coherent list. If you can't, draw what it should look like and correct your code accordingly.

Comment: @DiveshJethani The first iteration will run fine since the faulty branch isn't taken. Any subsequent iteration is [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). That means that you cannot rely on your observation that it runs fine as proof that it's OK. Undefined behavior can do anything, often it looks like it works fine but then causes your software to fail at a later point.

Comment: @DiveshJethani --  *That segment of the code runs perfectly*  -- Sorry to say, but C++ doesn't work this way.  Code that has undefined behavior can "run perfectly".  You need to get the experience in seeing that code is bad, and regardless how it runs, know that it is wrong.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I understand it now.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is full of accesses to uninitialized variables, dereferencing uninitialized members, and producing memory leaks

`if(head==NULL)`, where `head` is a local variable without initialiser

`while(temp->next!=NULL)`, where `temp` has just been created and `next` never assigned

`while(head->next!=NULL)`, where `head` is a function argument, which is possibly `NULL`

`struct Node* head = new (struct Node); head = takeInput()` leaks.

`struct Node* temp=new (struct Node); ... temp=temp->next` leaks.

Without changing your code to much, the following should work:

```
struct Node* takeInput(struct Node* head) { 
    cout<<"Enter element:";
    int data;
    cin>>data;
    while(data!=-1){
        struct Node* newNode=new (struct Node);
        newNode->data=data;
        newNode->next=NULL;

        if(head==NULL){
            head=newNode;
        }
        else{
            struct Node* temp=head;  // start at the head
            while(temp->next!=NULL){
                temp=temp->next;
            }
            temp->next=newNode;
        }
        cout<<"Enter next element: ";
        cin>>data;
    }
    return head;
}

void print(struct Node* head){


    while(head!=NULL){  // test head, not it's successor
        cout<<head->data<<"->";
        head=head->next;
    }
}

int main(){
    struct Node* head = takeInput(NULL);

    print(head);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`struct Node* head;` is uninitialised when you check `if(head==NULL)` it almost certainly evaluates to false. The only thing you do in the else is leak memory and then you return an uninitialised pointer. When you try to use it just segfault as it should.

change `struct Node* head;` to `struct Node* head=NULL;` and `struct Node* temp=new (struct Node);` to `struct Node* temp=head;`

in main change `struct Node* head = new (struct Node);` to `struct Node* head = takeInput();` and remember to deallocate the memory

Comment: Works perfectly now.. Thank you so much!

Comment: "`if(head==NULL)` it almost certainly evaluates to false" - is not true; it is undefined behaviour and may lead to a crash, may be optimised away completely, may ... I think it is worth to note that we may not assume anything on a result of evaluation if undefined behaviour is in place...